# Keyboard is dismissing on onChangeText event everytime I type in React Native Paper Input

Tags: react-native

I have an input that everytime I type something in it, the Android emulator keyboard dismisses, so it's impossible to write an entire phrase in it without clicking on the input many times...

I couldn't find anything related to this problem in Stackoverflow, can someone help please?

Here is the code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Container from "../../../components/General/Container";
import FilesList from "../../../components/Modules/Quality/FilesList";
import FilterButton from "../../../components/Modules/Quality/FilterButton";
import CategorySelector from "../../../components/Modules/Quality/CategorySelector";
import QualityApi from "../../../http/modules/quality/QualityApi";
import {Subheading, TextInput} from "react-native-paper";
import {ScrollView} from "react-native";
import {RNToasty} from "react-native-toasty";

function DocumentsScreen(props) {

    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null);
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
    const [filtering, setFiltering] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchCategories();
    }, []);

    function fetchCategories() {
        QualityApi.getCategories()
            .then(function(result) {
                if (Array.isArray(result)) {
                    setCategories(result);
                }
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }

    function listFiles() {
        setFiltering(true);
        QualityApi.getDocuments(name, selectedCategory)
            .then(function(result) {
                setFiles(result);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err)
                RNToasty.Error({
                    title: 'Ocorreu um erro ao tentar buscar os documentos.'
                })
            })
            .finally(function() {
                setFiltering(false);
            })
    }

    function onChangeName(e) {
        setName(e);
    }

    return(
        <Container>
            <ScrollView>
                <CategorySelector
                    values={categories}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        setSelectedCategory(e.id);
                    }}
                    selected={selectedCategory} />

                <Subheading style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
                    Nome do Arquivo
                </Subheading>

                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={(e) => onChangeName(e)}
                    dark={true}
                    value={name}
                />

                <FilterButton onPress={listFiles} isLoading={filtering} />

                <FilesList files={files} isLoading={filtering} />

            </ScrollView>
        </Container>
    );
}


export default DocumentsScreen;
```

I also tried to change the input to React Native Input and have the same problem.

Comment: Have a try in the physical device as emulator leads to many issues run time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried in the physical device and I'm having the same problem. If I extract the input to another component with it's own state, I don't have this problem, but I need the name state in the DocumentsScreen

Comment: I think there must be something else wrong as per the code it should not behave like you told.

Comment: I think this is happening because of my Container component... It's basically a View receiving the children as a prop and returning this children inside. If I remove the container, it works, but why?